# SQL Server 2012 geometry - Load schema using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm creating:

```
public DataTable CreateEmptyTableGeometryPoint(int srid)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
        string.Format("SELECT * FROM Geometry_Point_SRID_{0}",srid), 
        connection);
    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    adapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);

    return dt;
}
```

Now, I tried:

```
DataTable dtGeometry = dal.CreateEmptyTableGeometryPoint(srid);
DataRow rowGeometry = dtGeometry.NewRow();

rowGeometry["Geometry"] = SqlGeometry.Point(100.0, 300.0, srid);
```

I get an `ArgumentException`.

Why do I get this exception? Can someone help me?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: It seems like the error must be on the `rowGeometry["Geometry"] = ...` line.  Is "Geometry" actually in the data table?  I tried this with one of my tables, and I got `System.ArgumentException: Column 'Geometry' does not belong to table ABC`. Does your `ArgumentException` show more details in the message?

Answer (score 0):

Add a break point after `DataRow rowGeometry = dtGeometry.NewRow()` and check your schema.

Double check the data type for the "Geometry" column. It may not have filled in correctly.

```
foreach(DataColumn column in rowGeometry.table.Columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(column.DataType);
}
```